# Count number of folders containing n files with python

Tags: python

I have a directory containing folders with image files. I want Python to give me back the number of folders that their files add up to a number like n.

The code that I tried is pretty ugly and contains a lot of loops and the answer it gives me seems to be incorrect.

```
import os


def countProcess(home_folder, noOfImg):
    noOfDir = 0
    noOfFiles = 0
    for base, dirs, file in os.walk(home_folder):
        dirs.sort()

        for directories in dirs:
            noOfDir += 1
            for _, _, files in os.walk(base + '/' + directories):
                for Files in files:
                    noOfFiles += 1
     
                    if noOfFiles == noOfImg:
                        return noOfDir


HOME_FOLDER = '/home/erfan/example/lfw/train'

print(countProcess(HOME_FOLDER, 100))
```

Comment: The whole point of `walk` is that it recursively gives you *all* files under your chosen root.  It doesn't make sense to have a nested `walk`.

Comment: Could I be able to write it with glob?

Comment: I don't know another alternative to os.walk

Comment: You count the number of folders containing n images, for example, right?

Comment: Do you want to count files directly within the folder to be equal to `noOfImg` or do you want to count files in a folder and _any_ of its subdirs? So if `folder1` has 10 files and `folder1/subfolder2` has 5 files, do you want to count the number of files in folder1 as 10+5 or only as 10?

Comment: @Hamzawi Yes that is the case

Comment: @aneroid I want to count the number of folders which contain 100 image files altogether for example

Comment: @ErfanTaghvaei That doesn't answer my question. Does that 100 count include files only directly **within any one directory** or does should the file count in **all its subdirectories** add to its parent dir's file count?

Comment: @aneroid all files are in folders and there does not exist any subdirectories in the folders. There's just files containing images.

Comment: @aneroid I just want to include images in my count

Comment: You want to print the name of the subfolder with its total number of images e.g., Subfolder1 = 200 images, Subfolder2 = 50 images, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrt

> I want Python to give me back the number of folders that their files add up to a number like n.
>
> all files are in folders and there does not exist any subdirectories in the folders. There's just files containing images.

You can do it like this, without needing to recurse other dirs yourself since [`os.walk()` already does that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

```py
def countProcess(home_folder, noOfImg):
    noOfDir = 0
    for _, _, files in os.walk(home_folder):
        if len(files) == noIfImg:
            noOfDir += 1
    return noOfDir
```

Since `True` evaluates to 1 and `False` to 0, it can be done as a one-liner:

```py
def countProcess(home_folder, noOfImg):
    return sum(len(files) == noIfImg for _, _, files in os.walk(home_folder))
```

---

Edit: If you don't want to count files in the root directory, add a flag to exclude the first loop, which is for the root dir provided as a param to `os.walk()`:

```py
def countProcess(home_folder, noOfImg):
    noOfDir = 0
    first = True
    for _, _, files in os.walk(home_folder):
        if not first and len(files) == noIfImg:
            noOfDir += 1
        first = False
    return noOfDir
```

Comment: That's nice but it includes the parent folder in counting, is it right?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The parameter `files` of `os.walk` is always just a list of files in the current directory. Run `for parent, dirs, files in os.walk(home_folder): print(parent, dirs, files)` and you'll see that. It's also [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

Comment: The `noOfDir` count is only increased for the directories that have as many files as `noOfImg`. So it's checking all directories but each one's filecount is individually checked. It doesn't include it's parent or it's subdir files.

Comment: Yes, in the link you mentioned is written: ```For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top *(including top itself)*```

Comment: I am sorry, I checked again with my example but it counts the files in the root directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234449/discussion-between-hamzawi-and-aneroid).

Comment: @Hamzawi I didn't check your username earlier and see now that you're not the OP. lol. I've reverted my edit. If the OP wants to exclude the root dir file count, I'll add that as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an slower alternative to `os.walk()`, a simple recursion using a `os.listdir()`. Be careful with `ret_dirs=[]` it's a mutable variable and the pointer persists thru the recursion.

```
import os

def get_num_nf(root, num, ret_dirs=[]):
    n_files = 0

    for entry in os.listdir(root):
        full_path = os.path.join(root, entry)

        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            get_num_nf(full_path, num)

        elif os.path.isfile(full_path):
            n_files += 1

    if n_files >= num:
        ret_dirs.append(root)

    return ret_dirs

if __name__ == '__main__':

    dirs = get_num_nf('./env', 100)

    print(len(dirs))
    for path in dirs:
        print(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want to count subfolders that contain n files only excluding the parent folder:

```
import os
import glob  

sum(len(glob.glob(i+'/*')) == n for i in glob.glob(ParentDir+'/*'))
```